# Why is MKUserLocation in my annotations?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocation, mkuserlocation

I want to calculate distance between user and all annotations.
My annotations come from a csv file which is parsed. My annotations are in a `Location` class. Everything works fine except the distance calculation.

To calculate the distance, I found **this code**:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)newLocation
{

    for (Location *annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [annotation coordinate];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = [[[self.mapView userLocation] location] coordinate];
    CLLocation *myLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude:coord.longitude];
    CLLocation *userLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:userCoordinate.latitude longitude:userCoordinate.longitude];

     annotation.distance = [myLoc distanceFromLocation:userLoc];


        NSLog(@"Distance is = %f", annotation.distance);
} // ! CRASH !

NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [self.mapView.annotations sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSNumber *first = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(Location*)a distance]];
    NSNumber *second = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(Location*)b distance]];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

**But** my app crash *before* the end of the loop. I discovered, with breakpoints, that there is a strange annotation (`MKUserLocation*` instead of `Location*`); After this `MKUserLocation*` one, the app crashes:

**Not OK (crash):**
[image]

**OK (no crash):**
[image]

Why is there `MKUserLocation` in my `self.mapView.annotations`? How to ignore it?

**Log:**

```
2014-09-22 06:01:47.965 MyFirstGPS2[472:60b] -[MKUserLocation setDistance:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9db0bb0
2014-09-22 06:01:48.030 MyFirstGPS2[472:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKUserLocation setDistance:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9db0bb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01d971e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01b168e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01e34243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01d8750b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01d870ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   MyFirstGPS2                         0x00005043 -[HPViewController mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:] + 1203
    6   MapKit                              0x006825e6 -[MKMapView(MKHeadingAdditions) _stopTrackingHeading] + 469
    7   MapKit                              0x00666a92 -[MKMapView _setUserTrackingMode:animated:fromTrackingButton:] + 301
    8   MapKit                              0x00666960 -[MKMapView setUserTrackingMode:animated:] + 56
    9   MapKit                              0x00682176 -[MKMapView(MKHeadingAdditions) disableHeadingTracking:] + 65
    10  MapKit                              0x00669524 -[MKMapView _didChangeRegionMidstream:] + 672
    11  MapKit                              0x00671fbd -[MKMapView mapLayerDidChangeVisibleRegion:] + 66
    12  VectorKit                           0x0407a15e -[VKMapView mapDidChangeVisibleRegion:] + 78
    13  VectorKit                           0x040821fe -[VKMapCanvas cameraControllerDidChangeCameraState:] + 46
    14  VectorKit                           0x0409f1f7 -[VKMapCameraController updatePanWithTranslation:] + 231
    15  VectorKit                           0x0408268f -[VKMapCanvas updatePanWithTranslation:] + 63
    16  VectorKit                           0x0407aca9 -[VKMapView updatePanWithTranslation:] + 73
    17  MapKit                              0x0069e30b -[MKMapGestureController handlePan:] + 530
    18  UIKit                               0x00b724f4 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 230
    19  UIKit                               0x00b71168 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 383
    20  UIKit                               0x00b72bdd -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60
    21  UIKit                               0x00b7613d ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 57
    22  UIKit                               0x00b760be _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 317
    23  UIKit                               0x00b6c7ac _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 199
    24  UIKit                               0x00817a5a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    25  UIKit                               0x00818971 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1021
    26  UIKit                               0x007ea5f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    27  UIKit                               0x007d4353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x01d2077f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x01d2010b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x01d3d1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x01d3c9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x01d3c7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x03acf5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x03acf42b GSEventRun + 104
    35  UIKit                               0x007d6f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    36  MyFirstGPS2                         0x00013592 main + 130
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x0258a701 start + 1
    38  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**Note**:  I'm using the code in this page to parse the csv file, I don't think that's the problem: http://blog.smartfrog.fr/post/32123941502/tutorial-ios-mapkit

Comment: See this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444109/9497800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MKUserLocation` is not a "strange" annotation.

It is the documented class of the user location (blue dot) annotation added by the map view when you set `showsUserLocation` to `YES`.

The map view's `annotations` array includes *all* annotations added to the map -- whether by you or by the map view (also note these will not be in any particular order).

To make sure you only process annotations of type `Location`, you can check the class of the annotation object before processing it using the `isKindOfClass` method.

If the annotation is not of that class, skip it (`continue` the loop).

You'll have a similar problem with the code that sorts the array since it will try to access the `distance` property on the `MKUserLocation` annotation.

Instead of trying to create a sorted array from the map view's `annotations` array, I suggest creating a separate array of just `Location` annotations in the for-loop (at the same time that you set `distance`) and then sort that array.

Example of using `isKindOfClass` in the for-loop and the sorting change:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)newLocation
{
    if (newLocation == nil) {
        //can happen if still waiting for user permission
        return;
    }
    if (!CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(newLocation.coordinate)) {
        //can happen if just resumed from some time in the background
        return;
    }

    //Declare and set user location variables outside the for-loop
    //since they won't be changing during the loop...
    CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = [[[self.mapView userLocation] location] coordinate];
    CLLocation *userLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:userCoordinate.latitude longitude:userCoordinate.longitude];

    //declare array in which you will put your Location annotations for sorting later...
    NSMutableArray *locAnnArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    //Declare the loop variable as a generic id<MKAnnotation>   
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
        //Before processing the annotation, check it it's of type Location...
        if (! [annotation isKindOfClass:[Location class]]) {
            continue;
        }

        //Cast annotation to Location so we can see the distance property...
        Location *locAnn = (Location *)annotation;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [locAnn coordinate];
        CLLocation *myLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude:coord.longitude];

        locAnn.distance = [myLoc distanceFromLocation:userLoc];

        NSLog(@"Distance is = %f", locAnn.distance);

        //Add Location annotation to local array for later sorting...   
        [locAnnArray addObject:locAnn];
    }

    //Sort our array of Location annotations...
    [locAnnArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSNumber *first = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(Location*)a distance]];
        NSNumber *second = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(Location*)b distance]];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];

    //do something with the sorted array...
    //...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you !! But how can I access the distance (and other informations of the annotations) in LocAnnArray ? I'm actually looking for print those informations on screen... Hope I will find shortly :/ I've one more question, to be sure: what if user location changes while the loop is executing ? Will didUpdateUserLocation called again before the end of the first call? Sorry for my questions I'm a beginner.